# Retrieve the matplotlib Artist that received a mouse click event in the click handler

Tags: python, matplotlib, click

I have a python program that creates a matplotlib figure and a number of rectangle artists that are added to it. Each artist installs a common click handler that is invoked when a mouse click occurs within rectangle. The problem is that I can't figure out how to determine which rectangle was clicked. The click event passed to the handler does include the location of the mouse when clicked but I'd have to test every rectangle to see in which one, that point is contained.

There has to be an easier way to do this.

Comment: Maybe [mplcursors](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is helpful in this case? The selección element gives access to the artist. If you don't want to annotation pop up, you can set `set.annotation.set_visible(False)`.

Comment: You didn't add any code, making it hard to guess what exactly you tried.  Did you check out [the pick event demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/event_handling/pick_event_demo.html) which has access to `event.artist`?

Answer (score 0):

The rectangles might have been added to the axe in various ways:

- If from `ax.add_collection(patch_collection)`, then the `event.artist` will be the whole `patch_collection`, but you can retrieve the index of the inner patch(es) that triggered it with `event.ind`.
- If from multiple `ax.add_patch(rectangle)`, then the `event.artist` will be the individual triggered rectangle.

Depending on it, you might need to handle the callback differently.

```py
from itertools import product
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

# Rectangles parameters
width = 1
height = 1
nrows = 5
ncols = 7
inbetween = 0.1
xx = np.arange(0, ncols, (width + inbetween))
yy = np.arange(0, nrows, (height + inbetween))

# Create two identical sets of rectangles (for 2 figures)
patches1 = []
patches2 = []
for xi, yi in product(xx, yy):
    square1 = Rectangle((xi, yi), width, height, fill=True, picker=True)
    square2 = Rectangle((xi, yi), width, height, fill=True, picker=True)
    patches1.append(square1)
    patches2.append(square2)

# Create figure
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(8, 4), subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))
ax1.set_xlim(-1, ncols * (width + inbetween) + 1)
ax1.set_ylim(-1, nrows * (height + inbetween) + 1)
ax2.set_xlim(-1, ncols * (width + inbetween) + 1)
ax2.set_ylim(-1, nrows * (height + inbetween) + 1)


# Fig 1: PatchCollection
patch_collection = PatchCollection(patches1, picker=True)
ax1.add_collection(patch_collection)
ax1.set_title("PatchCollection")

# Fig 2: Individual patches
for patch in patches2:
    ax2.add_patch(patch)
ax2.set_title("Individual patches")


# Callback
def on_pick(event):
    mouseevent = event.mouseevent
    artist = event.artist
    print(artist)
    if isinstance(artist, PatchCollection):
        patch_idx = event.ind[0]
        paths = artist.get_paths()
        # path = paths[patch_idx]
        facecolors = ["C0"] * len(paths)
        facecolors[patch_idx] = "red"
        # Need to set all facecolors at once
        artist.set_facecolor(facecolors)
        fig.canvas.draw()
    elif isinstance(artist, Rectangle):
        artist.set_facecolor("red")
        artist.set_edgecolor("green")
        fig.canvas.draw()


fig.canvas.mpl_connect("pick_event", on_pick)

plt.show()
```

[image: Grids of rectangles]